# Is CodeIgniter 3 Complete?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I know some people are using it (PyroCMS) but is CodeIgniter 3.0 complete and ready to be used in production?

I have been using CodeIgniter for many years and although I know it seems to be languishing at the moment it is just so easy to use.

UPDATE: The title of this question used to be "Is CodeIgniter 3 finished?". By this, I meant, is CodeIgniter complete and ready to use in production (not is it dead).

Comment: so before the haterade parade starts - if you *really* want to know whats going with codeigniter - just go to its github page. The develop branch is the most recent https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter now look at the CLOSED Issues list and take note how recent they are https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues?page=1&state=closed

Comment: also this company CI Bonfire is very interesting - they are very actively working with CI but taking a different approach - this is a recent post http://cibonfire.com/blog/codeigniter_is_dead_long_live_codeigniter So maybe this is something that would be helpful for you.

Comment: @cartalot There is no hatred from me, I still love CodeIgniter. I just want a definitive answer as to whether the code in GitHub which says it is v3 is ready to be used yet or not.

Comment: As of this writing, Codeigniter 3 is now  released

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:**

> Version 3 completed on March 30, 2015. See  [CodeIgniter - Change Log](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html)

**Original Reply:**

No, it's not finished. When it is - you'll see the release announcement on the EllisLab website.

Contrary to what is said in the comments though, this doesn't depend on the issues pending on github and it's not dead either.

Comment: your efforts are very much appreciated by many people. i didn't explain myself clearly enough - i was trying to point out that if they looked at the closed issues list on github - they would see that CI is not "languishing". the closed issues are recent -- which is very quick proof to anyone that CI is active. thanks again.

Comment: Yes. @Narf, your efforts have been herculean -- thanks you. Out of interest, what is preventing it being completed at the moment?

Comment: @Narf Does that mean it is safe to start using v3 if we are able to get by with an incomplete user guide? To put it another way, would it be better to start a new project now with the current v3 build or still use v2?

Comment: Well, I'll tell you this - I wouldn't start a project with 2.1.x.

Comment: That is why I am getting frustrated, the lack of communication fram EllisLabs -- I did start a project a little while ago with CI 2.1 (because I didn't know that and nor do most people).

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter is now owned by the British Columbia Institute of Technology.

As of January 26, 2015, the Codeigniter 3.0rc release candidate, its documentation, and relevant changelogs are [availble here.](http://www.codeigniter.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter 3.0.1 is now fully compeleted.
you can see changelog here:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

and Codeigniter 3.1 is in development!!!

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter has now released 3.0 Candidate version

http://www.codeigniter.com/download

CodeIgniter 3.x is the branch under active development.

A few issues remain to be resolved, and it will not be released until those are put to bed. Version 3 is almost ready for prime time, and many sites are actually using it in production already.

angularjs routing is enabled.